# Slideshow: Aligning Next Buttons to Slidepicture while keeping it responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, slideshow

I have the following problem: I have a working slideshow with each slide containing a picture and some text. There are also next and previous "buttons". The buttons are aligned with the parent slideshow-container div. Now i want the buttons to be aligned at the half point of the pictures in the slides, while still being responsive. You can find the code here:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
@import url("https://use.typekit.net/yoj6eqg.css");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Assistant, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Slides */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 62.5%;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}

.image {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 60vh;
}


/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */

.dot-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}


/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */

.dot:hover {
  background-color: #90bd49;
}

.active {
  background-color: #90bd49;
}


/* text color */

.text {
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  color: #7bd934;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Assistant, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .heading {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .text {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .prev,
  .next {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .mySlides {
    display: none;
    padding: 30px 50px 30px 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div style="background-image: url('https://wallpaperset.com/w/full/a/c/7/185665.jpg');" class="image"> </div>
    <p class="heading">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
      Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div style="background-image: url('https://wallpaperset.com/w/full/a/c/7/185665.jpg');" class="image"> </div>
    <p class="heading">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
      Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div style="background-image: url('https://wallpaperset.com/w/full/a/c/7/185665.jpg');" class="image"> </div>
    <p class="heading">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
      Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a></div>
<div class="dot-container">
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></div>
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></div>
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></div>
</div>
```

Or you can find it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cu7j41sx/1/)

I tried to implement the button div into each slide div, that did not work. Then in each background picture div, also not working. I know that i could just use media queries to adjust the top: x %,but that would only solve the problem at some breakpoints.

There has to be a responsive solution, that i just cant see. I would be very thankful if someone could help achieve my goal here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after trying out some things, i came up with a solution: Like i tried before, i added the "buttons" to each slide in the image div. Then i separated the buttons in the css part and added the top: 50%; and transform: translateY(-50%); properties to the div to make it always stay in the middle of the picture. Then i just needed to define my desired position. Because i wanted the buttons to be "out" of my container div, above a screen-size of 1300px, i applied left: -5,9% to the prev button and right: -5,9% to the next one. Because i defined the size of the button through padding, i would need to change the left and right properties of the buttons every time, when i would change the width of the whole container.

So still there is probably a better solution out there, but for now it works.

You can see the result [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jp9o8wu4/) or below

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1;}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length;}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Assistant&display=swap');


body {
  font-family: Assistant, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Slides */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 92%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin:auto;
  
}

/* Prev Button Position and Properties */
.prev {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50%;
  left: -5.9%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
  padding: 30px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Next Button Position and Properties */
.next {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50%;
  right: -5.9%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 30px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  user-select: none;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: white;
}
.image
{
position: relative;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 60vh;
}

/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
.dot-container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ddd;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #90bd49;
}
.active {
  background-color: #90bd49;
}

/* text color */
.text {
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  color: #7bd934;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "p22-underground", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .heading {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
  }

  .text {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0px 20px 10px 20px;
  }

  .prev {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 20px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: white;
  }
  .next {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 20px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: white;
  }

  .mySlides {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
  }
}

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1300px) {
  .heading {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
  }

  .text {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0px 20px 10px 20px;
  }

  .prev {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 20px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: white;
  }
  .next {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 20px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: white;
  }

  .mySlides {
    display: none;
    width: 92%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
<div class="mySlides">
<div style="background-image: url('https://wallpaperset.com/w/full/a/c/7/185665.jpg');" class="image">  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a></div>
<p class="heading">Lorem ipsum</p>
<p class="text">But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</p>
</div>
<div class="mySlides">
<div style="background-image: url('https://wallpaperset.com/w/full/a/c/7/185665.jpg');" class="image">  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a></div>
<p class="heading">Lorem ipsum</p>
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="mySlides">
<div style="background-image: url('https://wallpaperset.com/w/full/a/c/7/185665.jpg');" class="image">  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a></div>
<p class="heading">Lorem ipsum</p>
<p class="text">But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="dot-container">
<div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></div>
<div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></div>
<div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></div>
</div>
```